# Parts of speech in "I let him take the pen."

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech, functions

In the sentence

> I let him take the pen.

are the following mentioned functions correct?

*I* = subject
*let* = main verb
*him* = indirect Object
*take* = the second verb (bare infinitive)
*the pen* = Direct Object

Answer (score 2):

**I** = main subject.

**let** = main verb.

**him** = direct object of **let**, and subject of **take**.

**take** = subordinate verb. It's infinitive because its subject is a direct object.

**the pen** = direct object of subordinate verb.

Comment: What's called as an *infinitive*? *to + base form*? Some books state that *infinitive* is *to + base form* or just *base form*.

Comment: @Ustanak Different people use slightly different terminologies. Broadly speaking, _infinitive_ means both forms; _bare infinitive_ means the base form; and _to-infinitive_ means the form preceded by _to._ See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive). The form alone doesn't make it an infinitive, though. It has to play a role where it doesn't agree in person and number with its subject, because it doesn't assert anything (by itself).

Comment: I wouldn't go along with that. "Him" is the grammatical object of "let", but it is only the semantic subject of "take". The subordinate clause "take the pen" is subjectless like most non-finite clauses are, though the subject is understood as "him".

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me well, *let* is a transitive verb, "him" is a direct object.

Comment: I'm not sure about the function of the secondary verb. ''Second verb'', as franky says, is not very accurate.